Error sending files with q-uploader in quasar 2.xx
I am trying to use quasar q-uploader component with nodejs/multer.
After I add a file to send to q-uploader and click my button to send, I am getting the next error and req.files is empty into file controller:
error: 21/05/2024, 14:14:43 Error: Multipart: Boundary not found
    at new Multipart (/home/luiz/programas/grow/backend/node_modules/busboy/lib/types/multipart.js:233:13)
    at getInstance (/home/luiz/programas/grow/backend/node_modules/busboy/lib/index.js:33:12)
    at module.exports (/home/luiz/programas/grow/backend/node_modules/busboy/lib/index.js:56:10)
    ....

What am I missing here?
My front is:
// template
...
        <q-btn @click="doUploadFile">Salvar</q-btn>
        <q-uploader
          ref="refUploader"
          :factory="factoryFn"
          hide-upload-btn
          multiple
          :form-fields="formFields"
          :headers="headers"
          accept=".jpg, .png, image/jpeg, .pdf, .doc, .docx, .mp4, .xls, .xlsx, .jpeg, .zip, .ppt, .pptx, image/*"
        ></q-uploader>
...

// script
import api from 'myapi'
....
setup(){
  setup(_, { attrs }) {
    const refUploader = ref();
    const tokenAuth = 'xxxx'
    const token = "Bearer " + tokenAuth;
    const headers = computed(() => {
      return [
        { name: "Authorization", value: token },
        { name: "Content-Type", value: "multipart/form-data" },
      ];
    });
    const formFields = computed(() => {
      return []; 
    });

    const uploader = ref(null);

    function factoryFn(files) {
      const tunelId = 1
      const stageId = 2;
      const url = `${api.defaults.baseURL}/api/stage/${tunelId}/${stageId}`;
      console.log(url);
      return {
        url,
        method: "PUT",
      };
    }

    function doUploadFile(files) {
      const uploader = refUploader.value;
      uploader.upload();
    }
    return {
      headers,
      formFields,
      refUploader,
      doUploadFile,
      factoryFn,
    };
}

My back:
..
..
const storage = multer.memoryStorage();
const upload = multer({ storage });
const stageRoutes = express.Router();

// router
stageRoutes.put(
  "/api/stage/:tunelId/:stageId",
  isAuth,
  upload.array("files"),
  StageController.update
);

// StageController
export const update = async (
  req: Request,
  res: Response
): Promise<Response> => {
  const { tenantId } = (req as IRequest).user;
  const { tunelId, stageId } = req.params;

  const medias = req.files;
  console.log("files", medias); ==> empty, no data
.....
....  

